# iOS phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect vs Facebook iOS Application

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been trying to make [phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) cordova plugin *Simple* example work, and i've experienced a weired problem.

- First I **had** the **Facebook iOS application** on my iphone:

On my test application based on the *Simple* example, when i click the Login button, it just switches to the Facebook iOS app, and switches back to my application.

Clicking the "Me" button gives me an error `"an active access token must be used to query information about the current user"` which means **the login was not successful**

- Then I **removed** the **Facebook iOS application** from my iPhone:

It worked. It opens Safari with Facebook authorisation page, when i click OK it switches back to my application and the `auth.login` events are **successfully** fired.

Is this a known issue ? Is there a way to fix it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround:

in Facebook.m

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions {
  self.permissions = permissions;

 [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth: NO safariAuth:YES]; //Use Safari Auth instead of FB App
}
```

With this workaround Facebook iOS authorization will not be used, wheter installed or not.

[Github issue#25](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/issues/25)

Comment: Is there any way to implement this solution in android plugin?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723762/phongap-facebook-plugin-not-working-when-native-fb-app-is-installed